# Is logging in to a remote application the same as logging in to a server?

Tags: google-drive

I'll explain why I'm asking this and what I mean; I'm trying to sync a series of files I extract from our SQL database as scheduled tasks. I want to use Google Drive Sync to do this. The one issue I've realized is that I have to actually log in to the server to initiate the sync.

Then I had a realization; that I log on to the server every day to use a remote application. Do services and scheduled tasks intitate when a user logs on to a server via remote application? Or is it not the same at all as actually logging in?

*I would test myself but I'm waiting for my IT Admin to get back to me about first installing Drive Sync on the server.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you schedule a task using the windows task scheduler, you can choose whether they're executed only when you're logged on or even if you're not. However, a lot of applications rely on having a desktop session to work and get closed after the program reports an exit code for the application.

If you, for example, schedule a batchfile that copies the data to another server, this would work even without you being logged on locally or using RDP - it would do its job, terminate and report an exit code to the scheduler. This would not work for a syncclient that you expect to run all the time.

If you want to run an application without having a session on the machine, that's where windows services come in. I've [found a solution](http://www.myrtec.com.au/kb/331-running-google-drive-as-a-windows-service) that could work for you, creating a windows service for the sync client:

- Make sure that google drive is not configured to run on startup
- Download Microsofts srvany.exe, designed to create services from binaries, and put in the folder where google drive is installed to
- create the service via an elevated command prompt. Make sure the `binpath` is correct: `sc create GoogleDriveSync displayName= "Google Drive Service" start= auto obj= "<domain>\<username>" password= "<password>" binPath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\srvany.exe"`
- open the registry editor and navigate to your new service, if you used the above service name at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\GoogleDriveSync`, and create to subkey parameters

  - a new `string` named `Application` with the path to your `googledrivesync.exe` as value
  - a new `string` named `AppParameters` with the value `/autostart --noshow-confirmation_dialog_on_delete` to make sure there a no GUI messages
- open the `services.msc` and set your service to start automatically

Srvany has worked for me for other binaries, so it's well worth a shot.